# New PayPal Sandbox Test User Accounts

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to create a new PayPal Sandbox Test Buyer Account.

I did it couple of months ago using a very user friendly interface at http://developer.paypal.com

Now, I wanted to create a new account and just noticed that PayPal has changed everything all over again..

It is asking me to login using my real paypal account first of all, on developer website!!

Even if I do login using real details, It doesn't display create a new sandbox test user options AS IT ALWAYS DISPLAYED 2 MONTHS AGO!!

I am confused as where to create test user account?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You start by logging into sandbox with normal paypal account credentials

@ https://developer.paypal.com/

Click on accounts under the sandbox header. You should see a "create account" button at the top right.

Follow steps and done